# How Do I Find First Occurrence Of A Value In An Array In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I need some help on Excel, please.

I have a spreadsheet with customers' names down the leftmost column (Column A. Each customer has 5 ticket numbers. There is a column for each of the 5 ticket numbers (Columns B through F). I want to look in the range (B - F) to find a specific ticket number and then return the name of the customer holding that ticket number.

Any ideas how I do this, please? (It's **not** VLookUp, I've tried that already and that does the reverse of what I want to do.)

Comment: is the ticket numbers unique as in they will only occur once in B2:Fn

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I've finally found a solution that works for me, in the form of a user-defined formula: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530596/excel-lookup-within-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

In H2 , write the ticket number your looking for

In I2 put this formula

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(H2,$B:$B,0)),INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(H2,$C:$C,0))),INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(H2,$D:$D,0))),INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(H2,$E:$E,0))),INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(H2,$F:$F,0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$F$n=TicketNumber))=0,"",INDEX($A$1:$A$n,SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$F$n=TicketNumber)*ROW($B$2:$F$n))))
```

where `n` equals the last row in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions. I've finally found a solution that works for me, in the form of a user-defined formula: [excel lookup within multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530596/excel-lookup-within-multiple-columns)